# ASP.NET LINQ query for filter and loop through multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, linq

I have two separate domain model classes for "App" and "AgeGroup". The App Class is containing few basic integer and strings properties and so does the AgeGroup class.

What I'm trying to achieve is JSON output of all the apps by AppOrder with their properties, nested in their associated AgeGroups that are ordered by their GroupOrder property

**Required Example JSON Output Structure**

```
"Looped List of Age Groups, order by GroupOrder"
      "Looped List of Apps, order by App Order"

 First Age Group
    Foo App Name
        Foo App Icon
        Foo App Store URL
    Bar App Name
        Bar App Icon
        Bar App Store URL
 Second Age Group
    Tur App Name
        Tur App Icon
        Tur App Store URL
    Puk App Name
        Puk App Icon
        Puk App Store URL
  and so on...
```

**My Approach so far:**

Here is what I have in my **"App.cs"** Class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string StoreURL { get; set; }
public int AppOrder { get; set; }
public string AppIcon { get; set; }

public AgeGroup AgeGroup { get; set; }    // Linked to AgeGroup Class
public int AgeGroupId { get; set; }
```

In the **"AgeGroup.cs"** Class, I have following

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int GroupOrder { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and in the **AppsController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/groups")]

    public IHttpActionResult AppsByGroup ()
    {
        var apps = _context.Apps
            .OrderBy(a => a.AppOrder)
            .Select(a => new
            {
                a.Name,
                a.StoreURL,
                a.AppIcon,
                AgeGroup = a.AgeGroup.Name
            }).GroupBy(a => a.AgeGroup);

       return Json(apps);
    }
```

It gives me correct output but without AgeGroup Names.

```
[
  [ // Here I wanted the AgeGroup Name from the AgeGroup Table (Group A)
    {
        "Name": "First App for Group A",
        "StoreURL": "some string",
        "AppIcon": "icon string",
        "AgeGroup": "Group A"
    },
    {
        "Name": "2nd App Group A",
        "StoreURL": "aslfdj",
        "AppIcon": "asljf",
        "AgeGroup": "Group A"
    },
    {
        "Name": "3rd App Group A",
        "StoreURL": "aslfdj",
        "AppIcon": "alsfdj",
        "AgeGroup": "Group A"
    }
  ],
  [ // Here I wanted the AgeGroup Name from the AgeGroup Table (Group B)
    {
        "Name": "1st App GroupB",
        "StoreURL": "alsfdj",
        "AppIcon": "alsdjf",
        "AgeGroup": "Group B"
    },

//and so on...
```

Comment: What is the definition of `not working`? Can you share some sample data and expected output? What output you are getting with current code?

Comment: Not Working = Json response is empty. I'm clarifying my question further.

Comment: You should be using a `.GroupBy()` linq query (not nested loops in a view) and a view model to represent that data. Are you wanting a method that returns a `JsonResult`, and how are you using that in your view (e.g. making an ajax call)?

Comment: I think you would originally have a many-to-many relation but you already redesigned it to one-to-many by creating duplicate entries for the same app in different groups. If not, it would help if you don't name two entries as `App 1 for Group XYZ`

Comment: I'm creating a separate Controller to handle my api requests. This code is supposed to be executed in the api. The data is a dummy data. One app can be a part of only one age group at a time.

Comment: I tried adding a navigation property as suggested by Leibowitz but couldn't deal in the Controller.

Comment: *couldn't deal in the Controller* That doesn't say much.

Comment: Okay, any explanation for the negative vote?

Comment: @GertArnold Couldn't deal in the controller means, I had no idea how to use the navigation property in the LINQ query in the controller.

Comment: Why not? Leibowitz gives it to you on a plate. Your response to that is: I'll explain again, but that doesn't make clear why the answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your answer is quite close. My question bounty time is about to finish. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. See my updated question. I didn't quite successful in what I really wanted but I guess I'm done with it.

Comment: I'll need to study your edit, but I think it can work in significantly less code (I'll take a look in about 2-3 hours or so)

Comment: No worries, but you need to check only the AppsController.cs area and everything will be clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to make the code a bit easier to understand and debug, you start with view models to represent the data you want to return

```
public class AgeGroupVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AppVM> Apps { get; set; }
}
public class AppVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StoreURL { get; set; }
    public string AppIcon { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to order the data and group it by the `Name` property of `AgeGroup`

```
var data = _context.Apps
    .OrderBy(x => x.AgeGroup.GroupOrder) // order by AgeGroup first
    .ThenBy(x => x.AppOrder) // then by the AppOrder
    .GroupBy(x => x.AgeGroup.Name) // group by the AgeGroup
    .Select(x => new AgeGroupVM // project into the view model
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        Apps = x.Select(y => new AppVM
        {
            Name = y.Name,
            StoreURL = y.StoreURL,
            AppIcon = y.AppIcon
        })
    });
return Json(data);
```

Comment: SIR.... A bundle of thanks. It worked. Since I'm new in this, it will take time for me to understand the viewmodels technique completely and use it efficiently in practical. So far, it looks flawless.

Comment: BTW, OrderByGroup was intended for the groups to come in specific order. Here apps are ordered by GroupOrder.

Comment: I just went on the first comment in your code _Looped List of Age Groups, order by GroupOrder, Looped List of Apps, order by App Order_ which is what the code above does

Comment: **LIST of AGE GROUPS, Order by GroupOrder** is exactly what I meant but the code is showing **List of Apps OrderBy GroupOrder** and ThenBy **AppOrder**. Currently the answer below is what I have to use.

Comment: But since your approach is much neater, cleaner and easy to debug, I'd prefer to find a way to make use of it.

Comment: No its not - have you checked the fiddle? - the code first orders by `GroupOrder` so that if you have 2 `AgeGroup` with values say 1 and 2 for the `GroupOrder` property it will generate them in that order. Then it orders each `App` within each `AgeGroup` based on its `AppOrder` property

Comment: Notice how in the fiddle, that `Group A` has `GroupOrder = 1` and `Group B` has `GroupOrder = 2`. Now if you edit that fiddle to modify `Group A` to `GroupOrder = 3` then `Group B` will be shown first

Comment: You are right. Its working in the fiddle and I checked it but for some reason, it is still not working in the visual studio whereas the other code works as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158855/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tough-guy).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public IHttpActionResult AppsByGroup() {

   var apps = _context.Apps.OrderBy(a => a.AppOrder);
   var groups = _context.AgeGroups.OrderBy(g => g.GroupOrder);

   var result = groups.Select(x => new {
         AgeGroupName = x.Name,
         Apps = apps
           .Where(y => x.Id == y.AgeGroupId)
           .Select(y => new {
              AppName = y.Name,
              AppIcon = y.AppIcon,
              StoreURL = y.StoreURL
            })
         });

   return Json(result);
}
```

It gives the following output

```
[
{
    "AgeGroupName": "Group C",
    "Apps": [
        {
            "AppName": "C Group App",
            "AppIcon": "Some string",
            "StoreURL": "64"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "AgeGroupName": "Group A",
    "Apps": [
        {
            "AppName": "App 2nd for Group AA",
            "AppIcon": "Some string",
            "StoreURL": "654"
        },
        {
            "AppName": "App 1 for Group A",
            "AppIcon": "Some string",
            "StoreURL": "654"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "AgeGroupName": "Group B",
    "Apps": [
        {
            "AppName": "App 1 for Group B",
            "AppIcon": "Some string",
            "StoreURL": "31"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It gave me the closest result. The only unwanted thing is the word "App" in every header instead of AppName but I'm good with it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have one to many relationship (each AgeGroup contains many Apps, but each App can have only one AgeGroup). So you can change your AgeGroup class to something like this:

```
class AgeGroup {
 public ICollection<Apps> Apps { get; set; }
 // your other properties here

  public AgeGroup() {
   Apps = new Collection<Apps>();
 }
}
```

Add AgeGroup to DbContext(if you didn't do it before) and then in your AppsController you can do this:

```
public ActionResult GetAgeGroupsWithApps() {
 var ageGroups = _context.AgeGroups
     .Include(ageGroup => ageGroup.Apps)
     .OrderBy(ageGroup => ageGroup.Id)
     .ToList();

 foreach(var ageGroup in ageGroups) {
  foreach(var app in ageGroup.Apps) {
   app.AgeGroup = null;
  }
 }

 return Json(ageGroups);
}
```

Firstly we include AgeGroups Apps collection and order them by their IDs. 


The interesting part is that now we have list of AgeGroups, each AgeGroup has a collection of App objects and each App object has a reference to AgeGroup. 


If you try to serialize it to JSON, serializer will get stuck in a loop endlessly following the references between the objects. To avoid this we iterate through Apps in each AgeGroup and for every App object we set AgeGroup reference to null. 


When you do that you can serialize ageGroups collection without any problems. It will return JSON array of AgeGroup objects with nested associated Apps.


Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but for some reason it is showing me two errors. First in the  **.Where(ageGroup => ageGroup.Name == name)** is showing me an error "The name "name" does not exist in the current context". And the foreach statement can not operate on variable of type '?' because...it doesn't contain public definition of GetEnumerator"

Comment: Basically the errors get fixed if I delete the line with .Where clause.

Comment: Then if you don't want to filter AgeGroups by their name you can just delete this line of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I'm bothering you again. You clearly understood the problem (One to many relationships) but probably I couldn't explain properly. I have rephrased the question completely.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use _context.Apps because dont have the Apps navigation collection in your AgeGroup class.
But this should be working.

```
_context.AgeGroups 
.OrderBy(t=> GroupOrder)
.Select(t=> new AppFormViewModel 
{
      App = t,
      AgeGroup = _context.Apps.Where(x=> c.AgeGroupId == t.Id)
      .Select(x=> new 
      {
          AppIcon = x.AppIcon,
          AppStoreURL = x.StoreURL
      }).AsEnumerable()
}.ToList();
```

Comment: I just saw your answer but nope. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical scenario of two classes having association relationship between each other.Please go through the definition of association aggregation and composition so that you get a clear idea behind creating your classes in future.Coming to your problem the way I will solve it is first I will start making its skeleton.

```
public class AgeGroup 
{
    //Age Group Class 
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    [Jsonproperty("AgeGroup")]
    public string AgeGroupName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("App")]
    public List<Appclass> app { get; set; }

}

public class Appclass 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    [Jsonproperty("AppName")]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}

string yourjsonMethod(List<AgeGroup> ageGroup)
{
    string json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(agegroup);
    return json;          
}

List<AgeGroup> yourmethod2(string json){
    List<AgeGroup> list=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AgeGroup>>(json);
    return list;
}
```

Hope this helps :)