# ASP.Net Filter Dropdown list items from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, viewmodel

**Summary:**

I'm trying to use two DropDownList controls to filter the data that is currently being sorted and displayed in a view.

**What we are going to learn**
Creating the ViewController for One to Many and Many-to-Many relationships that could Filter the data using DropDownList

**Possible Causes**
If my DropdownList code is not terrible wrong, The ViewModel I'm using to display the data has no proper support for the DropDownList items.

In other words, the RazorView and my ViewModels are not compatible for what I'm trying to achieve. If I try to change my ViewModel or RazorView, I get an eldless loop of errors for my existing code.

OR The Linq Query needs an expert attention

**Here is FilterViewModel.cs**

```
    public IEnumerable <App>      Apps { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <AgeGroup> AgeGroups { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <ProductCode> ProductCodes { get; set; }
```

**Here is AppsController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult FilterApps(App app)
    {
        var apps = _context.Apps.ToList();
        var languages = _context.Languages.ToList();
        var productCodes = _context.ProductCodes.ToList();
        var platforms = _context.Platforms.ToList();
        var ageGroups = _context.AgeGroups.ToList();
        var viewModel = new FilterViewModel
        {
            AgeGroups = ageGroups,
            Languages = languages,
            Platforms = platforms,
            ProductCodes = productCodes,
            Apps = apps
            .Where(a => a.LanguageId == app.LanguageId && a.PlatformId == app.PlatformId)
     // I also tried all possible combinations :(a.Lanage.Id etc)
        };
        return View("FilterApps", viewModel);
    }
```

**Here is the FilterApps.cshtml**

```
@model Marketing.ViewModels.FilterViewModel
<h2>FilterApps</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterApps", "Apps", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.Languages,
      new SelectList(Model.Languages, "Id", "Name"),"Select Language",
      new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropDown" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Platforms, 
      new SelectList(Model.Platforms, "Id", "Name"), "Select Platform",
      new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();",
      @class = "form-control", @id = "dropDown" })

</div>
}

//The existing code below is working fine so far.
@foreach (var group in Model.AgeGroups)
  {
   <h4>@group.Name</h4>

     @foreach (var app in Model.Apps.OrderBy(a => a.AppOrder))
            {
                if (app.AgeGroupId == group.Id)
                {
                 @app.ProductCode.Name
                 @app.Name
                 @app.Platform.Name
                }
             }
   }
```

Probably unnecessary but I hope the additional information will help.

**Additional Information**

The App.cs is referencing all other tables e.g.

```
public Language Language { get; set; }
public int LanguageId { get; set; }

public Platform Platform { get; set; }
public int PlatformId { get; set; } 
and so on...
```

**What I have already tried**
Several breakpoints and Logs to track the data, I also tried to use the following but it ruins my existing sorting and grouping.

```
public App App { get; set; } //Instead of the IEnumerable<App>
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `Languages` and `Platforms` are). You view model needs additional properties say, `int SelectedLanguage` and `int SelectedPlatform` to bind your dropdownlists to. Are you wanting to display `Apps` based on the value of those 2 dropdownlists

Comment: And how are you using the other 4 properties in your view (are `Languages` and `Platforms` just for the dropdownlists - and if so they should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties)?

Comment: @ToughGuy Form submit on dropdown selection, seriously!!??

Comment: Agree with @JibinBalachandran. Do **NOT** do that (and do not give your dropdowns the same `id` attribute which is invalid html)

Comment: Your also posting back a completely different model so nothing would bind anyway. Its not really clear what you wanting to do with this, but certainly your view model is not correct.

Comment: We also need to know if all dropdownlists must actually have a selected option (for example can a use just query `apps` based on just a selected `Language` (and include all `Platforms`) which affects the the way you need to query your data.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I want to display Apps based on the value of these 2 dropdownlists. I'm showing the data in a table of Apps where the platform is shown for each app so YES to your second question. Jibin, I do not have any other idea of filtering the apps other than to submit the form. I copied pasted thats why Ids are same. I'll change. YES to your last question.

Comment: @ToughGuy, What we mean is that you should have a submit button to submit (I'll explain why in an answer - but that might take a while because there is a lot to be explained). But just to clarify again - your saying a user must select an option from both dropdowns - i.e. they cannot filter the results by just `LanguageId` or `PlatformId`

Comment: In addition, if a user navigates to `..Apps/FilterApps` will you display all `Apps` initially, or do you require that the url require query string values for the selected `Language` and `Platform` so that its initially filtered?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm saying that initially I'm going to display all apps when I navigate to Apps/FilterApps and if I choose any of the drop down (Language or Platform) All apps must be filtered by either language/platform / or both. (1 Language All platforms / 1 Platform All Languages / Any platform Any Language / All Platform All Languages).

Comment: OK, I have drafted the answer, but now I need to make a few changes so that you can filter by either/or

Comment: Since it is not a public portal, I'm not too worried about the security as only authorized person is going to see the page. But yes I'm not looking for a potentially harmful vulnerability in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First you cannot bind a `<select>` element to a collection of complex objects. A `<select>` posts back the value of its selected option (which will be an `int` assuming the `Id` property of `Language` is `int`).

Next the view in the model is `FilterViewModel` (and your generating form controls with `name` attributes based on those properties), but your posting back to a different model (`App`) which does not contain those properties so nothing would bind anyway.

Your adding a `null` label option ("Select Language") and if that were selected, it would post a `null` value which would cause your query to fail.

There are also some bad practices which I have noted below.

Your view model should be

```
public class AppsFilterVM
{
    public int? Language { get; set; }
    public int? Platform { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LanguageOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PlatformOptions { get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable <App> Apps { get; set; }
}
```

Its not clear what `AgeGroups` and `ProductCodes` are for so I have omitted them in the code above, and from your comments, I have assumed that the user can filter by either `Language` or `Platform` or both

The controller code would be

```
public ActionResult FilterApps(AppsFilterVM model)
{
    var apps = _context.Apps;
    if (model.Language.HasValue)
    {
        apps = apps.Where(x => x.LanguageId == model.Language.Value);
    }
    if (model.Platform.HasValue)
    {
        apps = apps.Where(x => x.PlatformId == model.Platform.Value);
    }
    model.Apps = apps;
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(AppsFilterVM model)
{
    // populate the selectlists
    var languages = _context.Languages;
    var platforms = _context.Platforms
    model.LanguageOptions = new SelectList(languages, "Id", "Name");
    model.PlatformOptions = new SelectList(platforms , "Id", "Name");
}
```

Then in the view (note its making a GET, not a POST)

```
@model.AppsFilterVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterApps", "Apps", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Language)
    @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Language, Model.LanguageOptions, "No filter")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Language) 
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Platform)
    @Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.Platform, Model.PlatformOptions, "No filter")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Platform) 
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
@foreach (var group in Model.AgeGroups)
{
    ....
```

There a a few other thing you should not be doing. Your giving both `<select>` elements the same `id` attribute which is invalid html (the `DropDownListFor()` method already generates a unique `id` based on the property name).

You should not submit a form based on the `change` event of a `<select>` Not only is it unexpected behavior, if a user uses the keyboard to navigate through options (e.g. using the arrow keys, or typing a character to go to the first option starting with that letter, then the form will be immediately submitted. In addition, the user might select an option from the 2nd dropdownlist first, which would immediately post before they have a chance to select the option in the first one. Allow the user to make their selections, check them, and then submit the form when they choose to.

Your view should not contain linq queries, and your grouping and ordering should be done in the controller before you pass the model to the view. Your `Apps` property should in fact be a view model containing a property for the group name, and a collection property for the Apps, (similar to the view models in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108961/asp-net-linq-query-for-filter-and-loop-through-multiple-tables)) so that the view is simply

```
@foreach(var group in Model.AgeGroups)
{
    @group.Name
    foreach (var app in group.Apps)
    {
        @app.ProductCode
        @app.Name
        @app.Platform
    }
}
```

You should also consider using ajax to submit your form, which would call separate server method that returns a partial view of just the `Apps`, and update the DOM in the success callback, which would improve performance. For an example, refer [Rendering partial view on button click in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc/29142790#29142790).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. However I'm having issues on few places. It's giving me (explicit conversion: missing cast error) `apps = apps.Where(x => x.LanguageId == model.Language)`

Comment: That make no sense - are you sure you used `var apps = _context.Apps;` previously (you do not add `.ToList()` as per the code in your question - the query returns a `IQueryable<App>`)

Comment: I tried with .ToList() and with heck of more options but for some reason, it is not working. https://pasteboard.co/GU33GVg.png

Comment: No, do use `.ToList()` What are the exact details of the error message?

Comment: You may need to use `== model.Language.Value)`

Comment: Still no luck :( but this code works   `var apps = _context.Apps
                .Where(x => x.LanguageId == model.Language && x.PlatformId == model.Platform);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159220/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tough-guy).

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Models.App>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.App>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I already tried all the combinations, with and without ToList with .Value or Without .Value https://pasteboard.co/GU3Zckc.png

Comment: Moving on to the next issue, I am using this query code `var apps = _context.Apps
                .Where(x => x.LanguageId == model.Language && x.PlatformId == model.Platform);` and in the razorview the syntax is showing error (AgeGroup doesn't contain definition for Apps). https://pasteboard.co/GU426tv.png